# Function for showing info about table results

Tags: javascript, dom, html-table

**what i want my function to do:**

on first page
"Showing 1 to 7 of 11 results"

second page
"Showing 7 to 11 of 11 results"

etc.

**variables I have:**

page - what page you are on (1,2,3...)

records_per_page - how many results are showing per page (7)

objJson.length - how many results there are

numPages() - calculates number of pages

**My current function is showing:**

result on first page - "Showing 1 to 7 of 11"

result on second page - "Showing 2 to 14 of 11"

```
let changePage = function(page) {
               const listingTable = document.getElementById('listingTable');
     
               if (page < 1) {
                   page = 1;
               } 
               if (page > (numPages() -1)) {
                   page = numPages();
               }

               listingTable.innerHTML = "";

     
               for(let i = (page -1) * records_per_page; i < (page * records_per_page) && i < objJson.length; i++) {
                    let dataTable = document.getElementById("dataTable_info")
                    .innerHTML = `Showing ${page} to ${(page) * records_per_page} of ${objJson.length}`;
                    console.log(i)
                    

                    const tr = document.createElement("tr");

                   const content = `
                   <td>${objJson[i]._id}</td>
                   <td>${objJson[i].firstName}</td>
                   <td>${objJson[i].email}</td>
                   <td>${objJson[i].role}</td>
                   <td>${objJson[i].createdAt.slice(0, 10)}</td>
                   <td>${objJson[i].updatedAt.slice(0, 10)}</td>`;
                   
                   tr.innerHTML = content;
                   listingTable.appendChild(tr);
               }
               checkButtonOpacity();
               selectedPage();
               
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this logic.

```
function f(currentPage, totalPage) {
    const pageCount = 1;
    let pages = '',
        firstVisiblePage = currentPage <= pageCount ? 1 : currentPage - pageCount,
        lastVisiblePage = totalPage - currentPage <= pageCount ? totalPage : currentPage + pageCount;

    if (firstVisiblePage > 1) {
        pages += `<li><a href="#" data-page="1">1</a>`;
        pages += `<li><a href="#">...</a>`;
    }

    for (let i = firstVisiblePage; i <= lastVisiblePage; i++) {
        const page = i,
            className = currentPage === page ? "current" : "";

        pages += `<li><a class="${className}" href="#" data-page="${page}">${page}</a>`;
    }

    if (totalPage - currentPage > pageCount) {
        pages += `<li><a href="#">...</a>`;
    }

    if (lastVisiblePage < totalPage) {
        pages += `<li><a href="#" data-page="${totalPage}">${totalPage}</a>`
    }

    const nextPage = currentPage < totalPage ? currentPage + 1 : -1;
    const prevPage = currentPage > 1 ? currentPage - 1 : -1;

    return `
        <nav data-pagination>
            <a id="prevPage" class="btn-page-control" href="#" data-page="${prevPage}"><i class=ion-chevron-left>&laquo;</i></a>
            <ul class="pages-ul">
                ${pages}
            </ul>
            <a id="nextPage" class="btn-page-control" href="#" data-page="${nextPage}"><i class=ion-chevron-right>&raquo;</i></a>
        </nav>`;
}
```